# Limit supremum of i.i.d. sequence

Tags: probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $X_n$ be i.i.d. sequence of random variables with $E|X_n| = \infty$. I showed,
\begin{equation}
\sum_n P(|X_n| > kn) = \infty \text{ for all } k\geq 1
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
\limsup_n \frac{|X_n|}{n} = \infty\quad a.s.
\end{equation}
Now, from here I need to claim that
\begin{equation}
\limsup_n \frac{|\sum_k^n X_k|}{n} = \infty \quad a.s.
\end{equation}
I am not sure how pass to summation from the result for each term. I suspect it is something standard that I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k$. Then we can write
$$
\frac{S_n}{n} = \frac{X_n}{n} + \frac{S_{n-1}}{n-1} \frac{n-1}{n}.
$$
Now if we assume $\mathbb{P}( \limsup \frac{|S_n|}{n} < \infty) > 0 $ this means that the sequence $\frac{S_n}n$ is bounded with positive probability. Hence, so is  $\frac{X_n}{n}$ from the above equality, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Hayk

Comment: @Jo', you're welcome!